# div to only be as wide as the text inside, not stretch to the end

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the pink div width to only be as wide as the text inside it, and not stretch to the end. The width is set to auto, which I assumed would only make it just big enough to fit the text in.

How can this be fixed without having a fixed div size?

thanks for any help

```css
#footer-right{
 float:left;
 width:360px;
 height:200px;
 background:#96F;
}
.footer-text-section-wrap{
 background:#f0f;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
}
footer-1{
 color:#333;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:0 0 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-right">
<div class="footer-text-section-wrap">
<footer-1>Get a Quote</footer-1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is a `<footer-1>`? i mean besides [invalid markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) i would use `<footer class="someClass"></footer>` to ensure valid markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<footer-1>` tag is [invalid markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) and should be replaced with `<footer class="footer-1">Get a quote </footer>` then modify your css to use `.footer-1`

As others have stated use the inline-block to make it display to width auto

You can read more about the [display css here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
#footer-right{
 float:left;
 width:360px;
 height:200px;
 background:#96F;
}
.footer-text-section-wrap{
 background:#f0f;
 width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
 height:auto;
}
.footer-1{
 color:#333;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:0 0 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-right">
<div class="footer-text-section-wrap">
<footer class="footer-1">Get a Quote</footer>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `inline-block`

```
footer-1{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Making it an inline element will have it size itself to the size of your text.

```css
#footer-right{
 float:left;
 width:360px;
 height:200px;
 background:#96F;
}
.footer-text-section-wrap{
 background:#f0f;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
footer-1{
    display: inline-block;
 color:#333;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:0 0 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-right">
<div class="footer-text-section-wrap">
<footer-1>Get a Quote</footer-1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `display:inline-block;` to footer-text-section-wrap. Set its width to auto.

```
.footer-text-section-wrap{
background:#f0f;
width:auto;
height:auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer-right{
  float:left;
  width:360px;
  height:200px;
  background:#96F;
}
.footer-text-section-wrap{
  background:#f0f;
  width:80px;
  height:auto;
}
footer-1{
  color:#333;
  font-weight:100;
  font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
  font-size:20px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:0 0 10px 0px;
}
```

This css will do what you are asking the reason width: auto didn't work properly is because of the parent div that had a fixed width and since divs by default have display: block it gives the child div the width of the parent. So display: inline-block will work as well if not better than putting a fixed width on the child.